# Java Spring MVC project suddenly very slow

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-mvc

my spring project suddenly became very slow, both on startup and serving some kind of request.
I didn't change anything in the web.xml \ spring-context, but it all became very slow.

The startup passed from around 5 seconds to 30, the login serving demands around 15 seconds and in the console spring seems to do about nothing.

To be clearer as possible, this is the startup spring log:

http://pastebin.com/DezpJRJb

During the startup process it seems to be very slow on inner bean instantiation.

```
07/02/2015 10:58:02 - DEBUG - (AbstractBeanFactory.java:247) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lastFmController'
```

In the spring-context.xml I declared the package to be scanned first when looking for a controller:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.lastfmmusicrecommender.controller" />
```

And until yesterday it all worked great, it seems something went wrong without reasons.

I also post web.xml \ spring-context.xml \ springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>LastFmCarMusicRecommender</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-context.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.lastfmmusicrecommender.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.lastfmmusicrecommender.controller" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.lastfmmusicrecommender.controller" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.lastfmmusicrecommender.controller" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.lastfmmusicrecommender.controller" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/fonts/" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Any chance you have an active breakpoint during startup in eclipse? I have seen this behavior. Is the startup also slow running it in a tomcat directly?

Comment: Could you try removing the versions in your links to xsd files? If they don't match the version you're using the IDE might try to download them from the web.

Comment: @MartinFrey thank you buddy, that was the issue... It's so strange as I didn't have any breakpoint during the startup, but removing breakpoints got the situation back to superfast startup.. what a strange behaviour